# Why do not the figures compilate when they are in a folder?

Tags: floats, compiling

I wanted to clear up my project folder and created a figure folder. Afterwards I changed the code for the integration of the figure but they are still not compiling in the pdf. This is the code:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Abbildungen/regelkreislauf.png}
    \caption{Text}
    \label{fig:regelkreislauf}
\end{figure}
```

The folder is called Abbildungen, I am using Overleaf.

Thanks!

Comment: Try using `./Abbildungen/regelkreislauf.png`

Comment: Welcome! It should work. Are you sure about the capitalization of the names (code/directory)? Overleaf *is* case sensitive.